# Android Q - how to list directory content with Storage Access Framework from c++

Tags: android, c++, storage-access-framework

I know how to list directory content with SAF from java with DocumentsContract. How can I do that from c++ without jumping to java and back, because all strings from java must be converted from jstring, and it is a lot strings. Is there api for c++?